# java Arraylist remove elements

Tags: java

Suppose there are 10 elements in ArrayList and if i have deleted 2 elements from the middle , so the arraylist will contain 8 elements , but will the capacity be 10 or reduced to 8 at that time.

Comment: it's not a homework question.

Comment: I recommend you to read implementation of ArrayList. It is pretty clear and good.

Answer (score 4):

The API states :

> Each ArrayList instance has a
>   capacity. The capacity is the size of
>   the array used to store the elements
>   in the list. It is always at least as
>   large as the list size. As elements
>   are added to an ArrayList, its
>   capacity grows automatically. **The
>   details of the growth policy are not
>   specified beyond the fact that adding
>   an element has constant amortized time
>   cost**.

and you can always test this empirically in your debugger.  After removing two elements, look at the array that backs the `ArrayList`, and see what it's size is.  Most likely, it's 10.

Comment: SO if i deleted 2 elements will the list contains capacity of 8 elements or 10 elements.

Comment: @gaurav, it's undefined. The specs allow it to either be 10 or 8 or whatever other number the implementation needs (an implementation might actually make the capacity be 20 if that makes more sense for speed). It's implementation specific.

Comment: To clarify this: The VMs JRE, OpenJDK etc implement the specification. As the specification does not define that part it is undefined. Of course it will have to have a specific size in reality, but that depends on your VM implementation then.

Comment: ArrayList is an abstract form of an array. ArrayList always has the size of how many elements are in there. So if you remove 2 from 10, it's 8. The underlaying array where the implementation of ArrayList actually uses is not promoted by ArrayList. Very probably it will not reduce in size, as that would cost time. They are probably only increased when more elements are needed, most implementations double their underlaying array size when the limit is reached.

Comment: The "capacity" of an ArrayList is infinite. It does not change by removing elements. Only hardware will limit it.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour depends on the implementation of the ArrayList. You can't rely on this kind of implementation details. The only thing you must consider is that the capacity is always greater or equal to the number of elements in your list. If you need the capacity to be exactly the number of elements (because you may want to reduce memory usage), you will have to ask it explicitly with the function `trimToSize()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may  change because suppose we create new array list by default JVM allocate say 10 continuous locations in memory .if you put 8 or 2 or zero it will be same .

But is you put 15 element then it will increase it to say 20 memory locations .But if you below 10 again it should release that memory and reduce to 10 default size .

This is dynamic allocation .For 1000 element list if you are removing the element and reduce to 2 then it is logical that it must release that memory .It should depend on number of elements removed.